# Check if user is valid for authentication only if uses database authenticable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

Users can sign into our application by OmniAuth or by email and password (but only if they were invited).

We have a method, which checks if the user can sign in by email and password as follow:

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && valid_for_authentication
end

private
# Check wheter user was invited or not   
def valid_for_authentication
  User.invitation_accepted.find_by(id: id).present?
end
```

This works fine, but when I want to log in by OmniAuth, this method will block me.
Can I specify to bypass this method if OmniAuth authentication is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check below method before executing active_for_authentication? lines

The below lines will If the returned some **res** data if login using omniauth add logic **unless res.present?**

```
def logged_using_omniauth? request
  res = nil
  omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  res = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid 
  (omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid']) if omniauth
  res  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I figure it out in another way. `active_for_authentication?` and `valid_for_authentication` was deleted.

Then in `app/models/user.rb` I defined following code based on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address#overwrite-devises-find_for_database_authentication-method-in-user-model

```
  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    if valid_for_database_authentication?(warden_conditions)
      super
    else
      throw :warden, message: not_allowed_for_authentication
    end
  end

  # Check wheter user was invited or not
  private_class_method def self.valid_for_database_authentication?(params)
    User.invitation_accepted.find_by(params).present?
  end

  private_class_method def self.not_allowed_for_authentication
    I18n.t('devise.failure.user.not_allowed_for_authentication')
  end
```